# How to programmatically select rows in vb6 Datagrid

Tags: ms-access, datagrid, vb6, ado

I have a VB6 Project I am creating and i have a method that searches and edits students from an access database. i need to code the program so it can select the student that was searched and modify it. I saw this webpage but it does not select the student, the user has to select it before making edits, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/195472 . How do i program it so it can select that particular row so the user can edit.
Code using the website:

```
Option Explicit
Dim connSearch As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rec As New ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
connSearch.Close
connSearch.Open connstr
rec.CursorLocation = adUseClient

  If cmbSearch.Text = "Last Name" Then
    rec.Open "Select * From Table1 where [Last Name] like '" & txtSearch.Text & "'", connSearch, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    frmStudents.cmdShowall.Enabled = True
    If rec.EOF Then
        MsgBox "No Student Found.", vbInformation, "Error"

    Else
        Set frmStudents.StudentTable.DataSource = rec
        MsgBox "Student found Successfully", vbInformation, "Success"
        ' Remove previously saved bookmark from collection
     If (frmStudents.StudentTable.SelBookmarks.Count <> 0) Then
        frmStudents.StudentTable.SelBookmarks.Remove 0
     End If
        ' Append your bookmark to the collection of selected rows
     frmStudents.StudentTable.SelBookmarks.Add rec.Bookmark
        frmSearch.Hide
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help. :)

**EDIT: Move code from comments to here**

```
Private Sub Form_Load() 
   connSearch.Open connstr 'open the connection 
   frmStudents.Adodc1.ConnectionString = conn.connstr 
   Set frmStudents.StudentTable.DataSource = frmStudents.Adodc1 
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the example. Shouldn't your datagrid datasource be set to the whole recordset - not just the matching lastname that you're doing? Where is your Form Load code that fills the Datagrid?

Comment: This looks like it's part of a module not a form - is it located in same form? Or are you just showing us some kind of extracted code?

Comment: i have two forms, one for searching for the students and one for the datagrid and controls. The code that i have supplied in the question is an extract from the search form. The next comment shows the form load code that retrieves the datagrid and the database.

Comment: `Private Sub Form_Load()
 connSearch.Open connstr
    frmStudents.Adodc1.ConnectionString = conn.connstr
    Set frmStudents.StudentTable.DataSource = frmStudents.Adodc1
    End Sub`
@dbmitch

Comment: Do you have a working example yet? This makes even less sense now. What is Adodc and how is it being defined - do you have other global variables at the top of your module?

Comment: the adodc is being called from the previous form (thats why it has frmstudents in front of it). and this is a form not a module. The search works perfectly, it just does not select the student to edit

Comment: You're resetting the datagrid datasource with the one student you found. I thought you wanted to just select the student from all of them. If you only have one on the screen it doesn't make sense to use a bookmark??

Comment: which way would be better, resetting the datagrid or using the bookmark to highlight the student?

Comment: Pick one or the other - you're trying to do both

Comment: how do i let the bookmark select the student that was searched. i removed the line `Set frmStudents.StudentTable.DataSource = rec` and it works, but the bookmark does not got to the student that was searched for. it just stays at the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using a recordset to fill the frmStudents.Adodc1 Datasource but for some reason you don't want to show that code.

Then in the code you try you're opening a new recordset to search for the student and assign a bookmark. That will not work.

If you want to show all the students - like the example shows - you need to leave the data source alone and do the find on the same recordset used by your datagrid.

It's hard for me to guess what that is since you're not showing me the Form's code - I assume the recordset is global withing the form's module - but maybe not?

Without that information I can guess at something, hoping maybe the translation will work.

**Replace this**

```
rec.Open "Select * From Table1 where [Last Name] like '" & txtSearch.Text & "'", connSearch, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
frmStudents.cmdShowall.Enabled = True
If rec.EOF Then
    MsgBox "No Student Found.", vbInformation, "Error"

Else
    Set frmStudents.StudentTable.DataSource = rec
    MsgBox "Student found Successfully", vbInformation, "Success"
    ' Remove previously saved bookmark from collection
 If (frmStudents.StudentTable.SelBookmarks.Count <> 0) Then
    frmStudents.StudentTable.SelBookmarks.Remove 0
 End If
    ' Append your bookmark to the collection of selected rows
 frmStudents.StudentTable.SelBookmarks.Add rec.Bookmark
    frmSearch.Hide
```

**With this**

```
Dim varBookmark as Variant

With frmStudents.StudentTable 

    varBookMark = .Bookmark

   ' Remove previously saved bookmark from collection
   If (.SelBookmarks.Count <> 0) Then
        .SelBookmarks.Remove 0
   End If
   .Recordset.Find  "[Last Name] like '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
   ' If Find method fails, notify user 
   ' If the search fails, the Recordset will point to either EOF or BOF. 
   If .Recordset.EOF or .Recordset.BOF Then
      Msgbox "No Student Found"
      ' Reset back to last selection
      .Recordset.Bookmark = varBookmark
   Else
      Msgbox "Student Found"
     .SelBookmarks.Add .Recordset.Bookmark
  Endif

End With
```

Ideally you'd just use the recordset variable that you assigned to `frmStudents.Adodc1` instead of `frmStudents.Adodc1.Recordset`, but you haven't shared that with me so maybe this will work for you

Comment: this is exactly what i need thanks, but i need verification that if the last name does not exist it shows a msgbox saying "user not found". Right now if the last name does not exist, it says **Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.**

Comment: It does not work because **NoMatch** does not exist after the recordset

Comment: Does `.EOF` exits? Can't you use Intellisense and see what's offered after you type in "Recordset." - you don't have enough code in your question for anyone here to simulate it.